# Hiding parameter prevents other parameters from refreshing

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have the first parameter (client drop down) that passes an ID to the second parameter to be used in the 3rd and 4th parameter.  During testing all the parameters are set to visible to verify what's being passed.  As soon as I hide that second parameter the rest don't refresh.  Again, visible, correct info flowing through, hidden, DOA.  I have this set up exactly like this on at least a dozen other reports with no issue.  I'm not real sure where this going wrong since I can see the correct value being passed while visible?

Comment: Is it failing in testing or after deployment with the hidden parameter?

Comment: @Kidiskidvogingogin in testing.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to duplicate your issue. While I can't find a reference to support my supposition, I believe that hidden parameters (even those with a default value) are not evaluated until rendering, which would explain this behavior. Data sets that drive parameter values are run prior to the report being rendered.

As you're talking about having trouble with dependencies between the parameter values, I assume you're using queries to drive your available values for parameters three and four. If this is the case, then simply embed the logic that relates the value(s) of parameter 1 to the value(s) of parameter 3 into the query that drives parameter 3's available values. By cutting out Parameter 2 and incorporating it into the query logic for parameter 3, you will work around this issue.

If you're having trouble accomplishing this, reply in a comment and I'll see if I can help. As it stands, I don't know enough about what you're trying to do to help any more.