# SSRS dynamic - parent parameter not passing to the child parameter if parent parameter is hidden

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2

I want to do as cascade parameter on my dates parameter - startdate, Enddate to be Set on Default values when I select some other Parameter1. I have function on sql side based on lets say "Parameter1" it returns startdate, enddate. But when I'm selecting other values for the parameter1 then startdate, enddate not gets updates dynamically.
So I did some code change on the dataset with + row_number as extension. Now I have updates dynamically on my dates with extension. I want to hide parameters startdate, enddate and I created startdateNew, enddateNew (date format calendar) by removing on expression that row_number extension.
After all that now I'm facing the issue that is parameter startdate, enddate are hidden it's not working dynamically. When they are visible it works fine.

Basicly hiding parameter prevents other dependent parameters from refreshing... how to handle it?

Comment: I found similar question(not solved) here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37037903/hiding-parameter-prevents-other-parameters-from-refreshing/67822149#67822149

Answer (score 0):

I was able to duplicate your issue. While I can't find a reference to support my supposition, I believe that hidden parameters (even those with a default value) are not evaluated until rendering, which would explain this behavior. Data sets that drive parameter values are run prior to the report being rendered.

As you're talking about having trouble with dependencies between the parameter values, I assume you're using queries to drive your available values for parameters three and four. If this is the case, then simply embed the logic that relates the value(s) of parameter 1 to the value(s) of parameter 3 into the query that drives parameter 3's available values. By cutting out Parameter 2 and incorporating it into the query logic for parameter 3, you will work around this issue.

If you're having trouble accomplishing this, reply in a comment and I'll see if I can help. As it stands, I don't know enough about what you're trying to do to help any more.

Comment: Thanks @ManishKumar. I saw this suggestion also before, but this not work for me. I'm wondering if there that we could use "public function" to get that value from hidden parameter.